# Issues about the signedness of char

Tags: c++, char, language-lawyer, signedness

According to the standard, whether `char` is signed or not is implementation-defined. This has caused me some trouble. Following are some examples:

1) Testing the most significant bit. If `char` is signed, I could simply compare the value against `0`. If unsigned, I compare the value against `128` instead. Neither of the two simple methods is generic and applies to both cases. In order to write portable code, it seems that I have to manipulate the bits directly, which is not neat.

2) Value assignment. Sometimes, I need to write a bit pattern to a `char` value. If `char` is unsigned, this can be done easily using hexadecimal notation, e.g., `char c = 0xff`. But this method does not apply when `char` is signed. Take `char c = 0xff` for example. `0xff` is beyond the the maximum value a signed `char` can hold. In such cases, the standard says the resulting value of `c` is implementation-defined.

So, does anybody have good ideas about the these two issues? With respect to the second one, I'm wondering whether `char c = '\xff'` is OK for both signed and unsigned `char`.

**NOTE:** It is sometimes needed to write explicit bit patterns to characters. See the example in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbsrtowcs.

Comment: If you care about the bit patterns, perhaps you should always be using `unsigned char`.

Comment: I only ever use char for characters or because I have to (streams etc) If I ever want some numbers, which just happen to be a byte in size, I always use an explicit signedness char.

Comment: Sometimes, what is needed is a character string. However, the values of the characters should be explicitly specified. See the example in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbsrtowcs.

Comment: testing MSB: `(x | 0x7F) != 0x7F`

Comment: I don't really see your reasoning for testing MSB. The MSB is the same bit for unsigned and signed.

Comment: "Take char c = 0xff for example. 0xff is beyond the the maximum value a signed char can hold. " - only if `CHAR_BIT==8`. If you're aiming for portable code, don't replace one assumption by another.

Comment: I think there is enough evidence to practically reckon that `char c = '\xff'` (and similarly `char str[] = "\xff\xff"`) works for both signed and unsigned `char`. The evidence I found is as follows: 1) The table in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape states that the representation of `'\xnn'` is `byte nn`. Note the use of the word `byte`. 2) The example in  en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbsrtowcs uses this. 3) The example in https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Non-ASCII_Characters uses this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) testing MSB: `(x | 0x7F) != 0x7F` (or `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char&>(x) & 0x80`)

2) `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char&>(x) = 0xFF;`

Note that `reinterpret_cast` is entirely appropriate if you want to treat the memory the character occupies as a collection of bits, bypassing the specific bit patterns associated with any given value in the `char` type.

Comment: For 1) I think `(unsigned char)c >= 128` is cleaner. For 2), how about a character string? I need to explicitly specify the bit patterns of the characters in the string as in the example of  en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbsrtowcs

Comment: For 1), `if (c & 0x80)` seems to be the cleanest. It is correct regardless of whether `c` is promoted as signed or unsigned.

Comment: @Lingxi: the reason I used 0x7F is because it's self-evidently correct... if you even have to ask whether `c & 0x80` is also correct, then you shouldn't use it because - at best - every programmer looking at your code later is likely to wonder the same thing.

Comment: That said, the worrying case is when `char` is signed, and the relevant passage is from 5/10 "if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank shall be converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.", so the character `c` is promoted to the `signed int` type of 0x80.  If the system happens to use twos-complement integer representations, then the bit at 0x80 will stay set.  If it uses a sign/magnitude representation, the sign bit will be moved to the most significant bit.  So, it's unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

If you really care about the signed-ness, just declare the variable as `signed char` or `unsigned char` as needed. No platform-independent bit-twiddling tricks required.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do what you want without worrying about signedness.

Hexadecimal describes bit pattern not the integral value. (see disclaimer)

So for 2. you said you can't assign bit patterns like this

> char c = 0xff

but you realy can do that, signed or not.

For 1, you may not be able to do the "compare with 0" trick, but you stil have several ways to check the most significant bit. One way is, shift to the right 7, shifting in zero's on the left, and then check if it's equal to 1. Independent of signedness.

As Tony D pointed out, (x | 0x7F) != 0x7F is a more portable way of doing it instead of shifting because it may not shift in zeros. Similarily, you could do x & 0x80 == 0x80.

Of course you can also do what Brian suggested and just use an unsigned char.

Disclaimer: Tony pointed out that 0x is actually an int and the conversion to char is implementation defined when the char can't hold the value or if the char is unsigned. However, no implementation is going to break the standard here. char c = 0xFF, weather or unsigned or not, will fill the bits, trust me. It will be extremely difficult to find an implementation that doesn't do that.

Comment: *"you can still shift to the right 7 and then check if it's equal to 1"* - the Standard leaves right shift of negative values implementation defined, so there's no guarantee that will work portably (5.8/3 "If E1
has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.")

Comment: `0xff ` is of type `int`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal.

Comment: I think assigning from `int` to `char` comes under 4.7/3 "If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and
bit-field width); otherwise, the value is ***implementation-defined***."

Comment: `char c = 0xFF` is implementation-defined if `char` is signed

Answer (score 0):

You can OR and AND the given value with the two `0x7F` and `0xFF` respectively to detect as well as remove its signed_ness.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to test the MSB is to make it the LSB: `char c = foo(); if ((c>>(CHAR_BIT-1)) & 1) ...`.

Setting a specific bitpattern is a bit more tricky. All-bits-one for instance may not necessarily be 0xff but could also be 0x7ff, ore more realistically 0xffff. Regardless, `~char(0)` is all-bits-one. Somewhat less obvious, so is `char(-1)`. If char is signed, that's clear; if unsigned this is still correct because unsigned type work modulo 2^N. Following that logic, `char(-128)` sets just the 8 bit regardless of how many bits there are in the char or whether it's signed.